# navbar positioning bug in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists, css-position

I am having a strange css positioning issue in chrome only. I have a menu `<ul>` for navigation that sometimes gets pushed down randomly. Refreshing the page always fixes the problem. Strangely, sometimes if I refresh the page when it is being displayed correctly it gets pushed down.

This is how it is supposed to look, and it does about half of the time:

[image]

And this is what happens when it gets pushed down for some reason.

[image]

The site is live, and you can experience the problem for yourself [here](http://brannondorsey.com). It might take some clicking around the site to get the `<ul>` to drop.

Here is the `html/php` that I am using:

```
<div class="header">
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="<?php echo url("home") ?>" class="title"><?php echo strtoupper($site->title())?></a>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($pages->visible() AS $p): ?>
    <li><a<?php echo ($p->isOpen()) ? ' class="active"' : '' ?> href="<?php echo (strtolower(($p->title)) == "work") ? url("home") : $p->url(); ?>"><?php echo html($p->title()) ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

And relevant `css`:

```
 div.header{
   height: 80px;
   background-color: #000000;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 div.header nav.navbar{
   width: 960px;
   margin: auto;
   padding-top: 20px;
 }

 .navbar ul{
   float: right;
   padding-top: 10px;
   display: inline;
   list-style-type: none;
 }

.navbar ul li{
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
 }

.navbar a.title{
  width: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26pt;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

Again, I am only experiencing this problem in google chrome.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does defining font sizes in pixels or ems help?

Comment: I made `navbar ul li` have `font-size: 16px;` but I don't think it changed anything.

Comment: hey Brannon, site loox great :) ...i'm not seeing the bug on my end??? (OSX 10.8.4 chrome 28)

Comment: Hmm... It is actually happening still, just slightly more rarely than when I posted this. Im using OSX 10.7.1 chrome 28. I thought I might have spotted it today on IOS 6 safari as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never figured the problem out but I used absolute positioning as a workaround.