# header navigation positioning bug in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float, css-position

So, I'm having a strange issue in chrome (Version 33.0.1750.154) where, when the site is first opened, the navigation in my header gets pushed down and outside of the header for some reason. Upon refreshing the site, the navigation returns to where it should be and doesn't cause any issues. I've noticed that the positioning is messed up ONLY when you first open the site (for example, if I close the tab and reopen it a few times, it'll randomly happen but it won't ever happen if I refresh the site). It works exactly like it should in Firefox.

The site is live here: http://ayushman.us/

Similar problem in this question ([navbar positioning bug in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822050/navbar-positioning-bug-in-chrome/)) but the solution doesn't seem to be working for me. Any ideas?

Note: If you open the link and the header is aligned, close the tab and reopen at least three times (closing each time it works fine). For some reason, the third time is when it messes up for me.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but I cannot reproduce the problem in Chrome35 on Win. Has the problem been solved?